# Unable to debug Moonlight plugin in firefox

Tags: linux, mono, gdb, moonlight

On loading libmoonplugin.so I am getting following following error
Unable to read JIT descriptor from remote memory!

*Following is complete GDB session*

GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.2-1ubuntu11) 7.2

Reading symbols from /usr/lib/firefox-4.0/firefox-bin...(no debugging symbols found)...done.

(gdb) symbol-file /usr/local/lib/moonlight/plugin/libmoonplugin.so

Reading symbols from /usr/local/lib/moonlight/plugin/libmoonplugin.so...done.

**Unable to read JIT descriptor from remote memory!**

(gdb) run ~/Desktop/default.html

Starting program: /usr/lib/firefox-4.0/firefox-bin ~/Desktop/default.html

**Unable to read JIT descriptor from remote memory!**

(gdb)

Answer (score 0):

To debug firefox+moonlight the easiest is to start firefox, then attach gdb:

- Open firefox.
- Run this in a terminal to get the pid of the firefox process:

```sh
ps aux | grep firefox-bin
```

- Now start gdb, attaching to the firefox binary:

```sh
gdb program (pid)  
(lots of output from gdb)  
(gdb) continue
```

- Then in firefox just navigate to the web page you want to debug.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am able to debug using what you have mentioned as well as using "firefox -g -d gdb". However symbol table for libmoonplugin.so is not loading once I navigate to website with silverlight content and so I am not able to attach a breakpoint in moonlight classes

Comment: The .so is probably stripped, so it doesn't contain symbol information. In this case you'll need to build moonlight from source to debug. That said, what's the problem you're having in the first place?